# Titanium Appcelerator - couldn't find module ti.storekit

Tags: iphone, module, titanium, storekit

I'm getting this error running my app on a simulator or device: `[ERROR] :  Script Error Couldn't find module: ti.storekit`.  The device shows a red screen with the same error.  I have unzipped the module into ~/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/iphone/.  In that directory I now have ti.storekit/3.0.0/.  I have this in my tiapp.xml:

```
<module platform="iphone" version="3.0.0">ti.storekit</module>
```

I've trolled google, this site, and the appcelerator forum and found no solutions that work for me.

Titanium SDK: Titanium Command-Line Interface, CLI version 3.4.0, Titanium SDK version 3.4.0.GA

Platform & version: iOS 6.1

Device: iPod 5

Host Operating System: OSX Mavericks

Titanium Studio: 3.4.0.201409261227

I don't see anything else relevant in any logs but I am happy to post anything.  Anybody have any ideas?  Thanks for your time.

Comment: have you done "ti clean"?

Comment: Yes, it didn't help (though I did it from the studio, I assume running a terminal command does the same thing).

Comment: Have you tried installing the module using Titanium Studio instead of unzipping it yourself?

Comment: I think I tried that at one point and since it didn't work, I moved on to the manual method.  However, I just created an empty project, added storekit, and it ran with no errors.  So it appears to be a problem with the app, not with Studio.

Comment: you can also try to install module using [gitt.io](http://gitt.io) via CLI.

Comment: I ran "npm install gittio" and it seemed to install without error, but now if I run any gittio command it just says "command not found".

Comment: @nasch its needs to be a global: http://gitt.io/cli `[sudo] npm install -g gittio`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem was a second empty `modules` tag in the tiapp.xml file.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.storekit

download this module and add it in module directory of titanium studio.