# ti.storekit - Could not find a valid Titanium module

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

First, I have looked at [this stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26492278/titanium-appcelerator-couldnt-find-module-ti-storekit), and it's not solving my problem. I have downloaded ti.storekit into Appcelerator/Titanium modules folder (mac), then selected/added the module from the Appcelerator Studio 4.0 TiApp Editor. When I select the module it appears loaded and valid in my Ti project. When I try to run my iOS app in the simulator, I get this error:

```
[WARN] :   Could not find a valid Titanium module id=ti.storekit version=latest platform=iphone deploy-type=development
[ERROR] :  Could not find all required Titanium Modules:
[ERROR] :     id: ti.storekit    version: latest     platform: iphone    deploy-type: development
TRACE  | titanium exited with exit code 1
ERROR  | Error: ti run exited with error code 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/natej/.appcelerator/install/4.0.1/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/plugins/run.js:84:66)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:12)
```

I cannot figure out what to do differently. In the above Stack post I mentioned, they say to put version 3.0.0 in the xml, which I tried, and it did not good. I can't tell what version the ti.storekit is on github, I looked everywhere and cannot find it. I don't know if specifying the version the Ti xml will make any difference, or if I'm doing something else wrong.

And here is my tiapp.xml, with a few pieces obscured:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ti:app xmlns:ti="http://ti.appcelerator.org">
    <guid>de545a1xxxx-a06a0a24cd55</guid>
    <deployment-targets>
        <target device="mobileweb">false</target>
        <target device="iphone">true</target>
        <target device="ipad">true</target>
        <target device="android">false</target>
    </deployment-targets>
    <sdk-version>4.0.0.GA</sdk-version>
    <id>com.acme.myapp</id>
    <name>My Cool App</name>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <publisher>Acme</publisher>
    <url>http://www.acme.com</url>
    <description>Fun app</description>
    <copyright>2015 by Acme.com</copyright>
    <icon>appicon.png</icon>
    <persistent-wifi>false</persistent-wifi>
    <prerendered-icon>false</prerendered-icon>
    <statusbar-style>default</statusbar-style>
    <statusbar-hidden>false</statusbar-hidden>
    <fullscreen>false</fullscreen>
    <navbar-hidden>false</navbar-hidden>
    <analytics>true</analytics>
    <iphone>
        <orientations device="iphone">
            <orientation>Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT</orientation>
            <orientation>Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT</orientation>
        </orientations>
        <orientations device="ipad">
            <orientation>Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT</orientation>
            <orientation>Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT</orientation>
        </orientations>
    </iphone>
    <android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
    <modules>
        <module platform="iphone">ti.storekit</module>
    </modules>
    <property name="appc-app-id" type="string">5569c9ade5d789706791f60d</property>
</ti:app>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I've always put my third party modules in the `modules` directory of the project (same root level `tiapp.xml` is in): `./modules/ti.storekit/3.0.0/*` and added the version to the `<module>` tag.

Comment: I tried that previously (similar anyway) and it didn't work at all. It wasn't until I put it where Ti can find it that I got a little further...but still the error. There must be something more significant than just folder location going on here.

Comment: The module on GitHub is at version **3.1.2**.
Add this version to your TiApp.xml; If it's still doesn't work, try to build it and add the created `zip` file at the root of your app.

Comment: To make things clear: The ti.storekit module on Github is the raw module project. It is not build yet. Cloning the Github repo to the modules folder won't make it. You have to import it as a Titanium module project, then build it as iOS module with Studio. Afterwards Studio will prompt you to import the built module autmatically.

Comment: I imported ti-storekit but can't find any way to build/compile it. How is this done? And once done, how do I correctly reference it from my custom titanium project? Do I specify a path somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you download the source code or the actual distribution?

The distributions can be found at:
https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.storekit/releases

Comment: I had only gotten the source code. Sorry I'm new at Ti modules. Once I download the distribution, where do I put it, and how do I reference it from my Ti project?